# Object in current frame only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame

I have a Player movieclip object being placed on frames, where an example player is, then making the example player invisible. But when it runs the player is placed where the example is in the first frame, instead of in each current frame.

parent class:

```
playerStartX = exPlayer.x;
playerStartY = exPlayer.y;
```

Is there a way to either look only at the example in the current frame or else to remove only the example in the current frame after it has already been "copied"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understood your question completely, but maybe you should use an event handler for the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event. This event is dispatched in sync with the frame rate of your SWF. Your handler could look like this:

```
function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    playerStartX = exPlayer.x;
    playerStartY = exPlayer.y;
}
```

Because I don't no enough about how you structured/organized your MovieClips on the stage, I cannot say where to add the handler. But somewhere you have to do:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
```